# Passing a hidden variable into a link

Tags: php

I have this question please.
I have a link which once clicked gets the user to another URL outside my domain. that url gives the user the possibility to win a price, let's say , it's like this:

```
www.outsideurl.com/users_phone_number-winning_message.php
```

How can i make possible for this not to happen? I mean, i cannot controll the url of the outside URL, but, how can i send a link without the user being redirected there?

Because, i am a user, and once i have the link, i can submit it more than 100 and win 100 prices.

is there any way to hide the url, or anything like this..
Thanks...

Comment: It's very hard to understand the question as is. There is no way for you to "pass" information privately via a POST or GET request to another domain...

Comment: So, you want to click on a link, but not go to the link?

Comment: I thought, reading in the internet i could use framset, because, what i need is, not to show the url in the tab that opens.. , a way not to show the URL generated...

Comment: Wow, I bet the "prices" are REALLY good! Stop pushing this crap!

Comment: Hi rocket, yes, i need to click on that link, i need that link to be processed, but the user should not know the URL of that link..

Comment: @blerta: There's no way to direct somebody's browser to a URL without making that URL available to the user.  You can try to hide it from them, but if they want to see it they can.

Comment: Is it really necessary to have the phone number in the URL? Can't you hash it and compare it with a none hashed version in a map somewhere to retrieve it again?

Comment: @blerta Just think about your last comment a few seconds before posting the same question again ..

Comment: dbf... well, i could do that, but i'd need to colaborate with the other website... because it takes the URL and sends the message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call a link in the server side (so your user can't see it), but you want to send him the result of the page call, you may try :

```
echo file_get_contents("http://www.outsideurl.com/users_phone_number-winning_message.php");
```

But if there is relative links/form actions in this page your user will not be able to click/post on them.

Comment: Thank you... i gues, this might work :)

Comment: Don't down vote, if it is only to call the script and not view it's content, it might indeed work, though people who will sniff the traffic **will** eventually see the http call you make ..

Comment: A strange answer for a strange question.... Sorry! I do think everything can't be made using webservices.